# The properties set don't work in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a problem with properties in Kafka Streams. For example if I set this property in a node of topology:

```
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "window-exp-stream");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,KafkaConstants.KAFKA_BROKERS);
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG,EventTimeExtractor.class);
builder = new StreamsBuilder();
..........
..........
stream = new KafkaStreams(topology,config);
```

the timestamp extractor doesn't work.
If I use this property for the state store, it doesn't work either:

```
Map<String, String> changeLogConfigs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        changeLogConfigs.put("retention.ms","600000" ); //10minuti
        storeBuilder.withLoggingEnabled(changeLogConfigs);
        builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder);
```

What is the reason for this? Should I uninstall Kafka and Zookeeper and install them again?

Comment: This is a client problem, nothing to do with the server. Please show the StreamsConfig logs when you start the app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm new in kakfa, which file I have to see for to find streamconfig log ?

Comment: When your code starts (and has slf4j implementation on the classpath like logback), then you'll see the output of the actual runtime config values that you've set. How do you know if those values "dont work" without seeing that output?

Comment: OK thank you @OneCricketeer. Using slf4j I have: default.timestamp.extractor = class project.EventTimeExtractor . So  I mistake something in the use of the session window because it doesn't work as it should

Comment: You may want to try removing the default extractor config then explicitly setting it in the session. You can also add additional logging into your extractor class to see what it is doing

Comment: OK thank you, finally I solved the problem =)

Comment: Glad to hear. Feel free to answer below with the solution that worked for you

Comment: properties are set well. The error was in the class to extract the timestamp. I was converting the date to seconds instead of milliseconds . Stupid error =)